# Oracle SQL Check constraint between 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, check-constraints

I got 2 tables, `Persons` and `Relationships`.

The `Persons` table got only 2 fields for now: `ID` and `Age`.

`Relationships` have 3 fields: `Person_ID`, `Relative_ID` and `Relation`

What I wanna do is simple: on insertion\update to `Relationships` I want to check the following:

```
if Relation == 'child' and Persons[Person_ID].Age < Persons[Relative_ID].Age:
    Throw Exception
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I solved so other problems I had: I also got a "Workclass" field which I wanted to be one of 10 possible values so I created a "Workclasses" table and create a foreign key constraint from the persons_workclass field to the workclasses_name field.

Answer (score 1):

You should create trigger.

Try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER   my_trg
              BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Relationships
                 FOR EACH ROW
  declare
     function i_Age(id int) return int is
     li_res int;
     begin
       select p.Age
        into li_res 
        from Persons p 
        where p.ID= id 
         and rownum=1;
        return li_res;
    exception when no_data_found then
    return NULL; --or Throw Exception depend on your logic if some datas not found
     end;

     BEGIN
      IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
          IF :NEW.Relation == 'child' and i_Age(:NEW.Person_ID) < i_Age(:NEW.Relative_ID)  then 
           NULL; --Throw Exception or your logic
          END IF;
      END IF;
   END;
```

Comment: ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification
04079. 00000 -  "invalid trigger specification"
*Cause:    The create TRIGGER statement is invalid.
*Action:   Check the statement for correct syntax.

Comment: there should exists "declare" before "function" statement. By the way i reccomend you use Relation field numeric like 1,2,3 with look-up table consisting "child","married" .. etc.

Comment: yes, i have changed it, i have written it in notepad )) thank you

Comment: Any idea why this https://pastebin.com/jS6UM6H1 gives me an error of 

ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "USER7.MY_TRG", line 5
ORA-06512: at "USER7.MY_TRG", line 11
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'USER7.MY_TRG'

Comment: @Vecchiasignora ti prego

Comment: @CarsData do you have a primary key on persons.id?

Comment: you have primary key on persons by ID column, it means that ID is unique. if it isn't primary key try to catch ID which has created that error, try it after return "exception when  too many rows then" -- put or something to catch your input id

Comment: please show all your workflow, inserting and updating .... without trigger, especially working with Persons table in that session

Comment: Hey thanks for the help guys, eventually I did something a bit different. I posted my answer.

Comment: try to add exception "when no_data_found" you may have some problem in future

Comment: Note that this will fail in a multi-user setting because it relies on validating against data that can only be seen by the current session; it will not see data yet to be committed by other sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Check constraints (using the phrase in its technical meaning), with the exception of referential constraints, can't encode constraints on data from two different tables.

One technique you can use is to create a materialized view and have a constraint on the view. For example:

```
create materialized view relationship_check_mv
build immediate
refresh fast on commit
as
  select 1 as flag
  from   persons       p1
         join
         relationships r  on p1.id = r.person_id
         join
         persons       p2 on p2.id = r.relative_id
  where  r.relationship = 'child'
    and  p1.age < p2.age
```

Of course, you will have to create materialized view logs first, etc. So, this materialized view will have one row for each INVALID relationship. Then create a constraint on the materialized view, for example for the condition `flag = 0`. (Or, a bit simpler: change the MV to `select null as flag from....` and make the column `flag` to be `not null` in the MV.)

Whenever an attempt to insert an invalid row into the `relationships` table is made, the materialized view would be updated with a new row; but the check constraint on the MV prevents that, so the entire transaction will fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER child_parent_age_tr BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON RELATIONSHIPS FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE 
        child_age NUMBER; 
        parent_age NUMBER;

    BEGIN
        SELECT AGE INTO child_age FROM PERSONS WHERE ID = :NEW.PERSON_ID;
        SELECT AGE INTO parent_age FROM PERSONS WHERE ID = :NEW.RELATIVE_ID;
        IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
            IF :NEW.RELATION = 'child' AND child_age >= parent_age THEN
                RAISE INVALID_NUMBER;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: Note that this will fail in a multi-user setting because it relies on validating against data that can only be seen by the current session; it will not see data yet to be committed by other sessions.